# Replace existing managed package vf page by extension package vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, deployment, package

I have a managed package that is deployed in an org. In the managed package there is a vf page called **ShowInformation.vfp** that shows some records.

Now,  I have added new feature in **ShowInformation.vfp** page present in my dev org and added some links and buttons, some new vf pages with associated controllers. This **ShowInformation.vfp** page and other new vf pages needs to be sent as an extension.

Can the extension package replace already existing **ShowInformation.vfp** page present in an org?

If not, Is there any way by which i could replace already existing managed package vf page using extension vf page during the extension installation process.

Or, Can i just replace/add a particular section of managed package vf page with some additional links and button

Answer (score 0):

As you control both packages, in the original package page you can provide the option of doing a server-side forward to the extension page:

```
<apex:page ... action="{!init}">
    ....
</apex:page>
```

with this controller method:

```
public PageReference init() {

    // Make choice via custom metadata or custom settings
    if (...) {
        // Continue into the body of the original package page
        return null;
    } else {
        // Use the extension package page instead specified
        // via custom metadata or custom settings
        String extensionPackagePageUrl = ...;
        return new PageReference(extensionPackagePageUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this would be same as redirecting a user to a different page.

Comment: @Lambu Yes it is: the URL will change to the extension package URL.